# Why does `rsync <...> /path/to/someDir /path/to/otherDir` leave me with `/path/to/otherDir/someDir`, not syncing files from `someDir` into `otherDir`?

Tags: linux, synchronization, rsync

Why is my rsync doing that? It's basically just making a copy of the `someDir` folder inside `otherDir`. If I run the command again after making changes in `/path/to/someDir`, rsync will sync all files from `/path/to/someDir` to `/path/to/otherDir/someDir`. How do I get all the files inside `/path/to/someDir` synced to `/path/to/otherDir`.

This is what the command looks like that I'm excuting:

```
rsync --stats --compress --recursive --times --perms --links --delete --exclude ".git" --exclude "wp-content/upload" --exclude "wp-content/uploads" --exclude "wp-content/gallery" /path/to/someDir /path/to/otherDir
```

Comment: Pretty sure you just need a trailing `/` on `...otherDir/` to differentiate those cases.

Comment: If you're voting to close this question, you'd better put a comment so I know why.... I'm thinking maybe this is better for superuser??? If so, vote to migrate it, not close.

Comment: @BenJackson I tried that, but the result is the same.

Comment: @BenJackson Aaahhh, you were close. I needed the backslash after on `someDir/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync is one of the few commands that make a distinction between `/your/path` and `/your/path/`

When you don't use the trailing backslash you are referring to the directory, while when you use it you are referring to the contents of the directory.

Try

```
rsync --stats --compress --recursive --times --perms --links --delete --exclude ".git" --exclude "wp-content/upload" --exclude "wp-content/uploads" --exclude "wp-content/gallery" /path/to/someDir/ /path/to/otherDir
```

That extra trailing slash in `/path/to/someDir/` will make the contents of it available in `/path/to/otherDir`.

BTW: Don't be tempted to use `/path/to/someDir/*` as was suggested, that will give you problems when you have many files and it won't copy files with names beginning with `.`.

Answer (score 2):

The /path/to/someDir refers to the folder, someDir, not the files inside.
If you want instead to copy the files out of /path/to/someDir, try this:

```
rsync... /path/to/someDir/ /path/to/otherDir
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer hellork. I chose @PabloFernandez's because it was more informative though.